# CakePHP 2.0 can't access Model from its own Controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm still trying to migrate from CakePHP 1.3 to 2.0

I have a Controller UsersController and its Model User.
The class User has some constants which I could easily access from the UsersController using User::constant. But for CakePHP 2.0 it doesn't work: I get an error saying the User class is not found. It works if I `App::Import('Model', 'User');`.

Comment: I'm curious if this has to do with their built-in lazy loading in 2.0...

Comment: what is `User::constant`? And the `App::Import` should be unnecessary, at least providing you stick to the conventions in 2.0; can't say I've experienced this

Comment: @Ross `class User extends AppModel {
 const GROUP_ID_ADMIN = 1;
 const GROUP_ID_USER = 2;`. And I access the constant using `User::GROUP_ID_ADMIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sure has to do with their built-in lazy loading in 2.0!
you simple need to tell this file that it has other dependencies

do that at the very top of your UserController file:

```
<?php
App::uses('User', 'Model');
```

then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the controller name (in UsersController):

```
var $name = 'Users';
```

Or using the "uses" var (in other controllers:

```
public $uses = array('User');
```

Does that not work?

Comment: `var $name = 'Users';` was already there.. `public $uses = array('User');` doesn't help for other controllers.

Comment: additionally, the $name property can be totally omitted in all 2.0 classes

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the name of the model like that ?

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
}
```

Do you have others variables in your UsersController ?

Comment: Yes, I did. What do you mean, others variables?

Answer (score 0):

I set variables in the model like this:

```
//Person model
public $genders = array('m' => 'male', 'f' => 'female');
```

Then get them from the controller like this:

```
//People controller
$genders = $this->Person->genders;
```

No special code needed.  (Is this what you're talking about?)

Also, I don't believe you need to set the `$name` variable anywhere anymore - I think that was just for PHP 4. (not 100% on that part, but... I don't ever set that anymore, and my Cake2 apps run fine)

Comment: `$genders = $this->Person->genders;` works in my case either. But I can't access static data members or methords from the model using `User::foo`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you're saying it works, but you want to do it a different way?

Comment: well it works if I write `App::uses('User', 'Model');` like it was suggested. I'm just wondering why others didn't experience this problem.

Comment: or you mean why I want `User::foo` instead of `$this->User->foo`

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the model like this:

```
$this->loadModel('User');
```